# JBoss Fuse is not working in a Solaris machine

Tags: redhat, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I have downloaded jboss-fuse-full-6.0.0.redhat-024.zip from RedHat website and configured Fabric in my local laptop.  It worked fine.

However when I installed JBoss Fuse in a Solaris machine (with no internet connection), some of the bundles are in failure status and some are in grace period status.  Could some one help me how I can resolve this.

Is that because I don't have a Fuse subscription?  What is the work around?

[  20] [Active     ] [Failure     ] [       ] [   29] Apache Karaf :: Management (2.3.0.redhat-60024)

[  55] [Active     ] [GracePeriod ] [       ] [   35] Fuse Fabric :: ZooKeeper Service (7.2.0.redhat-024)

[  57] [Active     ] [GracePeriod ] [       ] [   40] Fuse Fabric :: Core (7.2.0.redhat-024)

[  59] [Active     ] [GracePeriod ] [       ] [   45] Fuse Fabric :: Boot Commands (7.2.0.redhat-024)

[ 101] [Active     ] [GracePeriod ] [       ] [   60] Fuse Fabric :: Maven Proxy (7.2.0.redhat-024)

I have created a custom offline repository at my local laptop (https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/Locate-CustomRepo.html)  and then copied the target directory to the Solaris machine.  Also updated the  etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file.  Please advise what else I need to do

Comment: Can you provide more details about what version of the solaris OS you are using?

Comment: uname -a SunOS sdpsrvr2-z5 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: This issue is now resolved.  One of the feature was missing and I installed the same.

Comment: Ah good to know. Can you mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trouble shooting I figured out that one of the Core feature was missing in the repository(jclouds-karaf) and added the same it worked.